# Maven pom.xml in META-INF vs pom.xml in Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, bazel

I'm trying to produce a Maven-compatible artefact using [bazel](https://bazel.build). I noticed that `mvn` puts some files inside `META-INF` directory in JAR archive (`file.jar/META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml` and `file.jar/META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.properties`)

Questions:

1. Are they needed to be able to successfully depend on my artifact from another project? I know you can disable them via a config option in `pom.xml` [ref](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-archive-configuration.html), which leads me to believe that you don't.
2. Are they used by `mvn` in any case whatsoever?
3. Can I use `pom.xml` *inside* on the JAR **instead** of `pom.xml` near my artifact in Maven repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have several jars in your Maven repository that do not contain a pom.xml. For maven, the revelant pom.xml is the one that is outside your artifact. In Nexus, you deploy a jar always along with a pom.xml and that is the one that counts.

So you need to publish a pom.xml along with your jar if you want to use it from Maven, but you do not need to put it inside. AFAIK you cannot change this behaviour.